# Flag Reload/Cache WinInet

Tags: delphi

estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma função em Delphi que executa Online um arquivo PHP que fornece o SERIAL do PROGRAMA Acontece, que quando executo essa função ele fica pegando o mesmo SERIAL, porque fica no CACHE da Máquina. Sei que existe uma FLAG que faz RELOAD no WinInet, algo parecido para limpar o cache, alguma ajuda ?

Segue meu código:

```
    function DownloadSerial(const Origem: string): string;
var
  SessaoHandle, UrlHandle : Pointer;
  TamanhoDados : DWORD;
  Dados : Array[0..1024] of Char;
  ABC: HMODULE;
begin
  Result := '';
  if (not Assigned(@InternetOpenA) or not Assigned(@InternetOpenUrlA) or not Assigned(@InternetReadFile) or not Assigned(@InternetCloseHandle)) then
  begin
    ABC := LoadLibrary( pChar('wininet.dll')) );
    if ABC <> 0 then
    begin
      @InternetOpenA := GetProcAddress(ABC, pChar('InternetOpenA')));
      @InternetOpenUrlA := GetProcAddress(ABC, pChar('InternetOpenUrlA')));
      @InternetReadFile := GetProcAddress(ABC, pChar('InternetReadFile')));
      @InternetCloseHandle := GetProcAddress(ABC, pChar('InternetCloseHandle')));
    end;
  end;

  if (Assigned(@InternetOpenA) and Assigned(@InternetOpenUrlA) and Assigned(@InternetReadFile) and Assigned(@InternetCloseHandle)) then
  begin
    SessaoHandle := InternetOpenA(nil, 0, nil, nil, 0);
    UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrlA(SessaoHandle, pChar(Origem), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    if UrlHandle <> nil then
    begin
      repeat
        InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Dados, SizeOf(Dados), TamanhoDados); //saida := saida + lpBuffer;
        Result := Result + string(Dados);
      until TamanhoDados = 0;
    end;
    InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
    InternetCloseHandle(SessaoHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a *flag* [`INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#internet_flag_reload) para fazer isso. Utilize esta *flag* ao chamar a função [`InternetOpenUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

No seu caso ficaria algo assim.

```
SessaoHandle := InternetOpen(nil, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrlA(SessaoHandle, pChar(Origem), nil, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD);
```

Ao usar essa *flag* você forçará o download do arquivo a partir da origem, e não do cache.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Sunstreaker, mas infelizmente não deu certo. eu botei um botão que execute aquela função acima. Eu clico uma vez ele pega o primeiro serial, clico de novo, deveria pegar o próximo da lista, porque o anterior já foi apagado, e infelizmente ele continua pegando o anterior. O que pode ser? Esquecemos de algo ?

Comment: deu certo sim, com essa segunda resposta...obrigado amigo!

Comment: estou testando agora.....deixa eu ver se consigo adaptar aqui que já marco a resposta. Obrigado!